# If return type is static does the method has to be static

Tags: java, static, singleton, static-methods, static-variables

I was studying Singleton and I came across the following code block

```
public class School {
private static School school;
private ArrayList<String> teachers;
private School(){
    teachers = new ArrayList<>();
    teachers.add("adam");
    teachers.add("john");
    teachers.add("jackson");
    teachers.add("jason");
}
public static School getInstance(){
    if (school==null)
        school=new School();
    return school;
}
public String getTeacher(){
    if (!(teachers.size() ==0))
        return teachers.remove(0);
    return "no teachers left";
}
```

}

As you can see the getInstance() method is static. I was wandering why?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

I know the return type is not static literally. The return type here is School. In Singleton, there has to be one instance of it using a static variable of the class it self, I get that part and make perfect sense. But my question was, why the method that sets the static variable has to be Static as well? That is the question.

Comment: What do you think _return type is static_ means? Why do you think so?

Answer (score 1):

Because that is the point of a Singleton, a single instance for the whole program.

If it wasn't static, you'd have to use an instance of the Singleton class to call the getInstance() method, which wouldn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

A common design pattern (Singletons) is the usage of an instance field of the class. That field must be static (so that it can be retrieved without a pre-existing instance of the class), and therefore, any method that accesses it must also be static.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually you the only one who understood my question. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The return type is not static. The method is static. See the JLS: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.2